# Finding runs of integers

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a problem that asks me to write a program that has a defined list (as the argument) and will then find all runs of `Y` consecutive numbers that increase or decrease by 1. It will then return the list of indices of the first element of each of these runs.

For example, if `Y = 3`, then `l1 = [1,2,3,5,10,9,8,9,10,11,7,8,7]` returns `[0,4,6,7]`. I got the code working somewhat, but it only works if I 'hard code' how many numbers I am checking. For example, if `Y = 3`, then my IF statement is checking `l1[i]`, `l1[i] + 1` and `l1[i] + 2`). I need it to work dynamically no matter what I set `Y` to.

Below is my code with my 'base logic':

```py
A = [1,2,3,5,10,9,8,9,10,11,7,8,7]

new_indices = []
for index, number in enumerate(A[:-2]):
    urgent_number = abs(A[index + 1])
    next_number = abs(A[index + 2])
    if (number + 1 == urgent_number and number + 2 == next_number) or (number - 1 == urgent_number and number - 2 == next_number):
        new_indices.append(index)

print(new_indices)
```

Below is my attempt to try and incorporate a while loop to do this dynamically. I'm close, but I just can't seem to figure it out:

```py
A = [1,2,3,5,10,9,8,9,10,11,7,8,7]
Y = 3  #length of list

new_indices = []
for index, number in enumerate(A[:-2]):
    urgent_number = abs(A[index + 1])
    next_number = abs(A[index + 2])
    x = 0
    while x < Y:
        if (number + 1 == urgent_number and number + 2 == next_number) or (number - 1 == urgent_number and number - 2 == next_number):
            new_indices.append(index)
        x += 1

print(new_indices)
```

prints out `[0,0,0,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7,7]`. However, I'm looking for `[0,4,6,7]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've gotten all the start indices and just need to remove the duplicates, you can do:

```py
from itertools import groupby

original_result = [0,0,0,4,4,4,6,6,6,7,7,7]
final_result = [key for key, _ in groupby(original_result)]
[key for key, _ in groupby(original_result)]
```

to get the desired output.

This outputs:

```py
[0, 4, 6, 7]
```

---

If you need to deal with variable run length specifically, you can find all the valid list slices that could make up a run, and then validate whether or not that slices makes up a run:

```py
A = [1,2,3,5,10,9,8,9,10,11,7,8,7]
RUN_LENGTH = 3
indices = []
for s in range(len(A) - RUN_LENGTH):
    is_incrementally_increasing = \
        all(i2 - i1 == 1 for i1, i2 in zip(A[s:s+RUN_LENGTH], A[s+1:s+RUN_LENGTH]))
    is_incrementally_decreasing = \
        all(i1 - i2 == 1 for i1, i2 in zip(A[s:s+RUN_LENGTH], A[s+1:s+RUN_LENGTH]))
    if is_incrementally_increasing or is_incrementally_decreasing:
        indices.append(s)

print(indices)
```

This also outputs:

```py
[0, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks Broken. But would you happen to know how I can somehow contort my logic to work if we had to check a number that's not a fixed number (in the above case it was 3)?

Comment: Sure, see my edit.

Comment: Wow, you are really good. Thank you so much. By the way, my response wasn't meant to be snarky in any way... I was just trying to ask :X

Comment: Didn't interpret your comment as snarky, no worries :) Have a great day!

Comment: you too! voted as best answer. thanks again

Comment: Just curious @BrokenBenchMark , what is that second approach you used , called?

Comment: Just trying to analyze pros / cons I guess for enrichment purposes I guess haha

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific term for the algorithm that's used in the second code snippet. It's a form of repeated list slicing, but that can be used to describe a lot of different algorithms.

Comment: Thank you @BrokenBenchmark sorry to bother. Was just curious. Thanks so much for sharing/ helping me add this to my tool belt.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```py
def dynamical(A):
    new_indices = []
    for index, number in enumerate(A[:-2]):
        urgent_number = abs(A[index + 1])
        next_number = abs(A[index + 2])
        if (number + 1 == urgent_number and number + 2 == next_number) or (number - 1 == urgent_number and number - 2 == next_number):
            new_indices.append(index)

    return new_indices
```

Comment: thanks Flow, but i was wondering how we would be able to use that same logic if we had to check a certain run_length (instead of three in this case). So for example: we would need to check number+1, number+2, number+3 if l=4 (not 3)

Comment: I am pretty sure that logic should work.